# Searching for MILP constraint to prevent alternation of integer variable

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Here is precisely my case:
Let's assume a variable `x[t]` which is a NonNegativeInteger smaller or equal than 3.

So `x[t]` can be `{0,1,2,3}`. It's indexed by a time serie.

I would like to prevent `x[t]` from alternating. 
Means I would like to disallow

```
x[0] = 0
x[1] = 1
x[2] = 0
```

but also

```
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2
x[2] = 1
```

and

```
x[0] = 2
x[1] = 3
x[2] = 2
```

I am looking for a constraint to disallow this. Three time steps must be involved in that constraint.

I've tried a couple of constraints. I am not sure if this is even possible with a simple constraint.

Maybe I have to add a variable to make this work. Do you have any experience with that kind of problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure increasing or decreasing order with below constraints:

x[t] + M(y-1) <= x[t+1]

x[t] + My  >= x[t+1]

y:Binary variable (same y is used at all equations)

M:Big number (bigger than possible the biggest value)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn’t explain my problem clearly. I want to prevent it from alternating. I don’t want to ensure increasing. So 0,1,0 should be prevented, but 0,1,1,0 should be possible.

Comment: I think that if "t" is {0,1,2,3}, using different binary varible (y) for last equation set will be enough.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Actually, if being increasing or decreasing order of the first three variable is enough for you, write the equation set for t = 0 and t=1 and make free x[3]. Because there is not relation between x[2] and x[3]. This allows 0,1, 1,0 or 1, 0, 0, 1.